# Lighting component not re-rendered if I invoke '$A.util.X' outside the component itself

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a global variable `hideBanner` inside a Visualforce page,

When a user clicks a variable which will toogle hideBanner value.

As you can see, I saved the lightning component JS object to `compHdlr`

In order for the later updates use.(Get rid of delete the DOM and create a new component inside the page again)

However, the addClass and removeClass just works on and off.

Is that because of the lifecycle problem or scope problem?

## JS code in an Visualforce page

```
    function initLoginForm() {
        $Lightning.use("c:lightningLoginApp", function () {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:sample",
                {},
                "customLogin",
                function (cmp) {
                    compHdlr = cmp;
                    renderForm(cmp);
                });
        });
    }


    function renderForm(cmp){
        ...
        if (bannerFlag === false) {
            $A.util.addClass(banner, "hideBanner");
        } else {
            $A.util.removeClass(banner, "hideBanner");
        }
        cmp.rerender()
        cmp.render()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a lifecycle issue.

Try this:

```
function renderForm(cmp){
   $A.getCallback(function() {
        if (bannerFlag === false) {
            $A.util.addClass(banner, "hideBanner");
        } else {
            $A.util.removeClass(banner, "hideBanner");
        }
        cmp.rerender()
        cmp.render()
   });
}
```

I'm pretty sure the scope is not a problem as you always get the calling scope when calling a sub function.

Also, you would have had some other $A is undefined error by this point.

Comment: It didn't do any update once I move all logic inside the `$A.getCallback`

Comment: What was this issue in the end?